# AngularJS & asp.net MVC - passing data to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

From this example http://xombe.com/2014/02/17/combine-angular-js-with-asp-net-mvc/, how do I pass data to the asp.net MVC controller?  In the example, he doesn't do this.  He accesses the controller and creates a new object, which is passed back to the view.  It's all read only.

Here's my Angular code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.updatefromview = function () {
                $http.post("@Url.Action("UpdateSomething", "Home", "testData")").success (function(data) {
                    $scope.somestring = data;
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
```

The "update()" triggered in a button:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="updatefromview()" value="update"/>
```

When the button is clicked, I go into the asp.net MVC controller but nothing is passed in.  The asp.net MVC controller signature looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateSomething(string somedata)
```

*somedata* is always null.  I'm expecting to see the text "testData".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CodeProject always misses the mark by posting convoluted examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing third argument   `"testData"` with `new{ somedata = "testData" }` in `Url.Action()` method.

The third parameter is **RouteValueDictionary** which is key value pair like thing so you need to specify it using anonymous type which is made by using `new { }`

Comment: Welcome. Can you check just one thing be renaming somdata variable to some other name and check that value posts or not

Comment: No - the value does not come through if the variable is renamed.  The javascript and .net parameters need to match.

Comment: That was the thing I needed to tell you so I asked you to try yourself