# How to pass data from component to controller?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Pass a string variable from the front end (HTML/.ts to C# controller).

I'm skimming through angular.io documentation and walkthroughs made by unofficial people. I watched videos and it appears none of it is relevant to my code. I started a new project(ASP.NET Core web application with Angular) in Visual Studio 2019. There are .ts components and .cs controllers. My HTML is set up to take a string input. I have tried using HTTP POST request and ajax requests. I may have done them incorrectly with the wrong arguments. I've consulted

[How to send data to an ASP.NET Controller with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919159/how-to-send-data-to-an-asp-net-controller-with-angular2)

[ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

[Passing Model data from View to Controller and using its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495717/passing-model-data-from-view-to-controller-and-using-its-values)

[AngularJS & asp.net MVC - passing data to controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205008/angularjs-asp-net-mvc-passing-data-to-controller)

and countless others not on StackOverflow.

.html

```
<input #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
Your name is: {{name}}
```

.ts

```
onKey(value: string)
{
    this.name = value;
}
```

I expect the name string to be available in the controller where I can print it out and later use it in a database.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you have? Provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, how are you sending it to asp.net core (your services) and your asp.net api controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create a demo using asp.net core Angular template.It passes data on Keyup.

1.home.component.html

```
<input #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
Your name is: {{name}}
```

2.home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  onKey(value: string):void {
    this.name = value;
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', this.name);
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44336/api/SampleData/TestName', formData).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

3.SampleData controller(/api/sampleData)

```
[HttpPost("TestName")]
public JsonResult TestName(string name)
    {
        //your logic
        return Json(name);
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per official guide line: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

```
onKey(event: any) { 
    console.log(event.target.value); 
    let inputValue = event.target.value;    
  }
```

Now `inputValue` will store your value from Input Field on Keyup Event.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question. in your defense, you can't really answer the question because it's kind of incoherent. Still it would be better to not answer it until such time as it is improved

Comment: I apologize for my quickly put together question. But as you can see, my .ts and .html file already has this functionality.